Blazor Server ProtectedBrowserStorage deserialization
My Blazor Server app has an AppState class and I want to use it for data exchange between components:
public class AppState
{
  public event Action OnChange;
  public int Counter { get; private set; }

  public void SetCounter(int num)
  {
    Counter = num;
    NotifyStateChanged();
  }

  private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}

Saving it in the Counter.cs:
private async Task IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount++;
    var appState = new AppState { Counter = currentCount };
    await SessionStorage.SetAsync(nameof(AppState), JsonSerializer.Serialize(appState));
}

But when I want to load it in the Weather.razor.cs component I get this error:

The JSON value could not be converted to AppState.

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        state = (await SessionStorage.GetAsync<AppState>(nameof(AppState))).Value;
    }
}

I tried to deserialize it but VS gave this error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AppState' to 'System.IO.Stream'

state = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppState?>((await SessionStorage.GetAsync<AppState>(nameof(AppState))).Value);

So I don't know how I get out data from the ProtectedBrowserStorage.

I have this solution:
Counter.cs
[Serializable]
public record Counter
{
  public int Number { get; set; }
}

AppState.cs
public class AppState
{
  public event Action? OnChange;
  public ProtectedSessionStorage SessionStorage { get; set; }

  public AppState(ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage)
  {
    SessionStorage = sessionStorage;
  }

  public async Task SetCounter(Counter counter)
  {
    await SessionStorage.SetAsync(nameof(Counter), JsonSerializer.Serialize(counter));
    NotifyStateChanged();
  }

  public async Task<Counter?> GetCounter()
  {
    NotifyStateChanged();
    var savedStateJson = await SessionStorage.GetAsync<string>(nameof(Counter));
    if (savedStateJson.Success)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Counter>(savedStateJson.Value!);
    } else
    {
        return new Counter { Number = 0 };
    }
  }

  private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}

Counter.cs
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject AppState AppState

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
  private int currentCount;

  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
  {
    if (firstRender)
    {
        currentCount = (await AppState.GetCounter())?.Number ?? 0;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
  }

  private async Task IncrementCount()
  {
    currentCount++;
    await AppState.SetCounter(new Data.Counter { Number = currentCount });
  }
}

The Weather.razor.cs component is similar. Notification between components is not ready yet.
